# How to get data from many tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am building a patient profile that has many tables such as medicines, treatments, x-ray, patient info, etc. all of them shared a patient ID, but I feel like it will have a big load on the service and take time, I searched a lot but I don't know if this approach is good or it could be better. here is an example of my eloquent code.

```
 $patient = Patient::with(['country' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'name');}])
        ->with(['city' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'name');}])
        ->with(['recourse' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'name');}])
        ->find($id);

$appointments = Appointment::where('patient_id', $id)                
->with(['branch' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->with(['doctor' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'first_name');}])
->with(['service_cat' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
->get();

$invoices = Invoice::select('id', 'creditor_cat_id', 'final_price', 'status')->where('patient_id', $id)
->with(['service_cat' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->get();


$medicine = Medicine::select('id', 'medicines_cats', 'start', 'end', 'status')->where('patient_id', $id)
->with(['medicinescats' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
->get();

$medicine_cat = Medicine_cat::all();

$disease = Disease::select('id', 'disease_cats', 'start', 'end', 'status')->where('patient_id', $id)
->with(['diseasecats' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
->get();

$disease_cat = Disease_cat::all();


$treatment = Treatment::select('id', 'treatment_cat_id', 'sessions', 'sessions_done', 'start', 'end', 'status')->where('patient_id', $id)
->with(['treatment_cat' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
->get();

$treatment_cat = Treatment_cat::all();


$session_pat = Session_pat::select('id', 'services_cat_id', 'treatment_id', 'invoice_id', 'status')->where('patient_id', $id)
->with(['service_cat' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'name');}])
->with(['treatment' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'sessions');}])
->with(['invoice' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('id', 'code', 'status');}])
->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
->get();

$service_cat_treat = Service_cat::where('type', 2)->get();
```

edited: in case I used hasMany, these tables have other tables connected as shown, so I did not know how to make it, for example, the patient table has treatment table, treatment table has 2 tables connected which are invoice and treatment category, and I did what is above to get all data from these connected tables

Comment: Why you not created the relationship to other tables from patient table with hasMany relationship, you would not need to write query for each table and also you can directly write it in your blade file.

Comment: Why don't you change Patient Profile table as a polymorphic table for medicines, treatments, x-ray, patient info, etc. It'll make it easier to query.

Comment: in case I used hasMany, these tables have other tables connected as shown, so I did not know how to make it, for example, the patient table has treatment table, treatment table has 2 tables connected which are invoice and treatment category

Comment: You have too many tables, to select in single query check post once - [https://romik-mk.medium.com/laravel-one-to-many-relation-in-single-query-5587697c259](https://romik-mk.medium.com/laravel-one-to-many-relation-in-single-query-5587697c259)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few options to choose from:

- [Combine all your queries into a single query](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) (Make a larger query, which will join together all the tables you need in your example)
- [Create a view](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) (Create a view of these tables within the database, then query using the view)
- [Create a materialized view](https://www.materialized.info/) (Creating a materialized view has it's benefits, though the upkeep of it is a bit tougher. Since materialized views actually hold real data, it means they need to be synced with the tables. They are only intended to be used when you need data fast and the data does not change often. In your case it could actually work, if you sync the materialized view every 5 min.) - Warning: **MySQL does not directly support materialized views.**

If you are trying to go for speed, then cache your results and only retrieve what was inserted after it.